# Pygame error: "module 'pygame' has no attribute 'get_ticks'"

Tags: python, pygame, attributes, python-module, pygame-clock

I am learnining pygame and I got error "module 'pygame' has no attribute 'get_ticks'". What do i have to do?
My code was: `start_ticks = p.get_ticks()`

Comment: My code was: "start_ticks = p.get_ticks()"

Comment: where is the rest of the code ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There is no `pygame.get_ticks()`. However, the [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time) module has a function [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock):

```py
import pygame as p
```

```py
start_ticks = p.time.get_ticks()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `pygame.get_ticks` but as Rabbid76 said pygame.time had get_ticks() so your code should be `pygame.time.get_ticks()` that should work.